# Android:name of the chart

Tags: android, charts, wifi, achartengine

I would like to know what is the name of the chart in this picture .I saw it in an application ,and i want to do the same work.
PS:i'm using achartengine.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: It's a normal line chart (with more than one curve - one per color - combined). Each curve has 3 values (0, y, 0). Just set the smoothness of the curve.

Comment: ok ,so i have to use line chart ,i'll work on it.Thank you

Comment: OOps! it's CubicLineChart, instead, sorry - some time passed since I had to do with these... Anyway, it's a variant of LineChart ;)

Comment: Do you know an example or tutorial using this chart ? @Vyger

Comment: here: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Comment: You're welcome. It's a bit confused as a sample, but it's the official aChartEngine omni-comprehensive example.